# Typescript having problems with comparing dates in Sequelize v6

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js

Consider the following piece of code. I thought this was perfectly fine. I think I have wrote something similar in javascript and it works, but typescript doesn't have the required definition it seems to allow me to continue.

```js
// get plan for recruiter and lead recruiter
const recruiterPlan = await getOneIncentivePlan({
    role: "recruiter",
    level: 1,
    starts_from: {
        [Op.lt]: new Date()
    }
});
```

`[Op.lt]` receives an error from typescript giving the following error.

`Object literal may only specify known properties, and '[Op.lt]' does not exist in type 'Date'.`

Is there any work around for this? I know we can write raw query too, but I am not sure how to do it since I am not really a SQL person. There has to be a way to write `sequelize.literal` query within the `where`, right?

I have tried using different operators, putting them in array but it's not working. It was supposedly solved in sequelize v5 as seen here - https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/10724

But it seems to have come back in v6.

Comment: Please show the definition of `getOneIncentivePlan`

Comment: It been a while, I have completely changed the whole thing to solve it. I think the error is an issue in the library as of now.